# Defining a gaussian wrapped kernel

Tags: probability

I know what [a gaussian kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28statistics%29#In_non-parametric_statistics) is, but I'm trying to figure out how what a gaussian *wrapped* kernel is.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandwich_wrap

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_distribution)